# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Благодаря такой «экономии», уже во время пуска новой или реконструированной технологической установки довольно часто возникают нештатные ситуации, наносящие материальный ущерб (,) в сотни раз превышающий «экономию» на качественном проектировании.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Нужна ли запятая?

**Нужна:** отделяет причастный оборот.

Comment: Что ж такое!.. А мне опять показалось, что здесь определяемое существительное не выражает нужного смысла. :(

Comment: Будьте проще.))) Случаев, когда "определяемое существительное не выражает нужного смысла", очень немного. Уберем последний причастный оборот — получим вполне себе законченное предложение, смысл не потерян.